# Cant type in hashtags, brackets or square brackets

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

i have a problem with my PC, i can't use certain key with Alt, my alt tab and alt shift functions perfectly but it's only the hashtags, brackets and square brackets that doesn't work. This is very problematic as I need these keys for programmation. BTW i have a french AZERTY keyboard and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Is this happening in all applications? Your post is unclear about what works or doesn't work, so please improve the description of the problem.

Comment: My alt key functions perfectly fine, but i can't use special characters like said above, and yes this happens in all my applications

Comment: You might need a new keyboard.

Comment: Keyboard configuration problem? Does anything at all show up with those keys? Any other key (not letters, typically) giving funny results?

Comment: Why are you expecting these glyphs on the alt key? Alt doesn't do anything to the letters typed on Windows. Alt/Gr invokes some accented letters, but Alt itself does nothing.

Comment: Nothing show up when i try to do the combinations, what's weird is that the field where i'm writing disables and i need to click it again to type

Comment: The problem persists even with alt gr, i can only do the @ symbol but that's all

Comment: Open the on-screen keyboard & see what you can see when you press alt/gr… should be this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy0UH.png

Comment: I tried that and the on-screen keyboard works normally but when i try to put the hashtag, the field of text just disappears like when i use my keyboard, very weird